# Java Loop not exiting properly when using boolean expression (JAVA) - Newbie

Tags: regex

Everytime I run the my function `SearchByID` it won't return the necessary `boolean` operators that I needed. The method reads to the `Employee.txt` files and read files one after another. What I did is I created a String array to store the splitted strings, and doing the `String.equalsIgnorCase()` method to check if the corresponding matches w/ the data on the file. Here is the code for the method

Code: SearchByID

```
public static boolean SearchByID(String ID){
    boolean bool = false;
    int idLoc = 3;
    try(BufferedReader bufr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(EMPLOYEE_TXT))){
        String line = bufr.readLine();
        /*Split the records into an array*/
        String[] lines;

        while(line !=null){
            //do the macthing of data here
            lines = line.split(";");
            if(lines[idLoc].equalsIgnoreCase(ID)){
                bool = true;
                break;
            }else{
                bool = false;
                break;
            }
        }
        bufr.close();
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
   return bool;
}
```

Here is the implementation of the method `SearchByID(`);

```
                    System.out.print("Search user by ID:");
                    String strID = sID.nextLine();

                    if(IOLibraries.SearchByID(strID)){
                        System.out.println("A match has been found");
                    }else{
                        System.out.println("No match found");
                    }
```

Content of the Employee.txt

```
kadi,bens;male;baliwasan grande;88-11;99111;arg11@gmail.com;400.0

doe,john;male;11311 asdd;99811;9911331;asdf@.sdfcom;500.0
```

What I really need to do is I need to read all the data on the file after that it should return the correct `boolean` values in order search for all the users on the `Employee.txt` file.

I could not retrieve if I search the values below the first entries. For example if i search for id 88-11 I could retrieve the data properly, however if I search below the first entry such as 99811 it would return `false` or "No match found" even if it is in the Employee.txt files.

Comment: What does this have to do with `regex`?

Comment: *Edit*: Only the first record is read in your while loop.

Comment: first things you need to learn are : 1. learn to properly indent your code 2. learn to follow Java naming conventions 3. learn to give meaningful names

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is you will always break out from the loop after reading the first line.

```
    while(line !=null){
    //do the macthing of data here
       lines = line.split(";");
        if(lines[idLoc].equalsIgnoreCase(ID)){
            bool = true;
             break;
        }else{
            bool = false;
            break;
        }
    }
```

Note the else block.  If first line does not match the ID, it will go into the `else` block, which declare that it is not found, and breaking out.

What you should do is

1. initialize `bool` (or better call it `found`) as `false` before the loop (for which you have done already)
2. Only break out of loop if you found the matching line

i.e. change the loop to something like

```
    while(line !=null){
       lines = line.split(";");
        if(lines[idLoc].equalsIgnoreCase(id)){
            found = true;
            break;
        }
    }
```